Installing AlmaLinux openssl-static.i686
How do I install the openssl-static package for 32 bit/i686?
I need to see /usr/lib/libssl.a so I can compile some C code.
In CentOS 7, I ran yum install openssl-static.i686, but for AlmaLinux 8 I do not have that option.
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: AlmaLinux
Description:    AlmaLinux release 8.10 (Cerulean Leopard)
Release:        8.10
Codename:       CeruleanLeopard


6/3/2024:
Tried a different web search, and found https://onexception.dev/news/1278807/installing-openssl-static-on-almalinux.  Trying it out, see if it works.  Will try other things based on this websearch.  Not sure if using epel-release repository is a good idea for Alma, so if anyone has an opinion, please pass it on.
6/12/2024, from one of answers, does not work, but was worth a try.  I also added the current list of repos, in case that helps:
[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> sudo dnf install openssl-static.i686 -y
ELevate                                          29 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS                             10 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:00    
AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS                             12 MB/s | 4.0 MB     00:00    
AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream                          16 kB/s | 4.2 kB     00:00    
AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream                          27 MB/s |  11 MB     00:00    
AlmaLinux 8 - Extras                             13 kB/s | 3.3 kB     00:00    
AlmaLinux 8 - Extras                             65 kB/s |  21 kB     00:00    
AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools                        8.3 MB/s | 2.9 MB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64  609 kB/s |  37 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64   20 MB/s |  14 MB     00:00    
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                      137 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    
MySQL Connectors Community                      144 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    
MySQL Connectors Community                       35 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    
MySQL Tools Community                           148 kB/s | 2.6 kB     00:00    
No match for argument: openssl-static.i686
Error: Unable to find a match: openssl-static.i686

[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> dnf repolist
repo id                                                             repo name
appstream                                                           AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream
baseos                                                              AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS
elevate                                                             ELevate
epel                                                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
extras                                                              AlmaLinux 8 - Extras
mysql-connectors-community                                          MySQL Connectors Community
mysql-connectors-community-i386                                     MySQL Connectors Community
mysql-tools-community                                               MySQL Tools Community
mysql80-community                                                   MySQL 8.0 Community Server
powertools                                                          AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools

6/17/2024 update:
[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> sudo dnf repolist                     
repo id                                                                     repo name
appstream                                                                   AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream
baseos                                                                      AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS
devel                                                                       AlmaLinux 8 - Devel
devel-debuginfo                                                             AlmaLinux 8 - Devel debuginfo
devel-source                                                                AlmaLinux 8 - Devel Source
elevate                                                                     ELevate
epel                                                                        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
extras                                                                      AlmaLinux 8 - Extras
mysql-connectors-community                                                  MySQL Connectors Community
mysql-connectors-community-i386                                             MySQL Connectors Community
mysql-tools-community                                                       MySQL Tools Community
mysql80-community                                                           MySQL 8.0 Community Server
powertools                                                                  AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools

[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: AlmaLinux
Description:    AlmaLinux release 8.10 (Cerulean Leopard)
Release:        8.10
Codename:       CeruleanLeopard

[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> sudo dnf install openssl-static.i686 -y
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:53 ago on Mon 17 Jun 2024 12:27:30 PM EDT.
No match for argument: openssl-static.i686
Error: Unable to find a match: openssl-static.i686
[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> sudo dnf install openssl-static -y
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:59 ago on Mon 17 Jun 2024 12:27:30 PM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.
=======================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                    Architecture                       Version                                         Repository                         Size
=======================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 openssl-static                             x86_64                             1:1.1.1k-12.el8_9                               devel                             1.9 M

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 1.9 M
Installed size: 13 M
Downloading Packages:
openssl-static-1.1.1k-12.el8_9.x86_64.rpm                                                                                              5.3 MB/s | 1.9 MB     00:00    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                  3.1 MB/s | 1.9 MB     00:00     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                               1/1 
  Installing       : openssl-static-1:1.1.1k-12.el8_9.x86_64                                                                                                       1/1 
  Running scriptlet: openssl-static-1:1.1.1k-12.el8_9.x86_64                                                                                                       1/1 
  Verifying        : openssl-static-1:1.1.1k-12.el8_9.x86_64                                                                                                       1/1 

Installed:
  openssl-static-1:1.1.1k-12.el8_9.x86_64                                                                                                                              

Complete!
[tonyb:v10_odbc:V3_44:mysql]> ls -lrt /usr/lib/libssl.a
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/libssl.a': No such file or directory

What am I missing?

On AlmaLinux 8, you should be able to install the 32-bit version of openssl-static using the following commands
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools

Install the package-
sudo dnf install openssl-static.i686

This should install the necessary libraries to /usr/lib/.

It cannot find a match for openssl-static.i686.  I will update my post with exactly what I did.  Too bad.  Any other ideas?  Have you actually done this on AlmaLinux 8?

Yes, I apologize for the oversight in the previous response. I've tested this on AlmaLinux 8 and realized there's a slight nuance.
AlmaLinux 8 doesn't directly provide a separate package for 32-bit OpenSSL static libraries. However, you can install them by following these steps:
Enable devel repo:
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled devel

Install the 32-bit Static OpenSSL Package:
sudo dnf install openssl-static.i686

After installation, you should find the necessary static libraries (including libssl.a) in /usr/lib/.
PowerTools Repository: If the above doesn't work, try enabling the PowerTools repository as well:
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools

You can verify the installation by running:
ls /usr/lib/libssl.a

This should list the 32-bit static library file.
Let me know if you encounter any further issues, sorry about the last answer

doesn't work - get "Error: No matching repo to modify: devel."  I already  tried enabling powertools, and that one does not have openssl-static.i686.  See my original post, and the 6/12 update.  I ran sudo dnf repolist --all | grep -i dev, and I see no development repo even available.  I then ran sudo dnf install almalinux-release-devel -y to install it, and that worked, BUT still cannot install the static library.  Please provide a full listing of the  repos.  Maybe that is my problem.  This is a tough one.  Thanks.

I guess I can also try just copying over the libraries from a CentOS 7 machine I have access to.  Not ideal, but for some reason installing 32 bit versions of libraries is proving tough with AlmaLinux.  I am just starting with openssl since if I figure that one out, I can probably figure out the other ones as well.  Incidentally, see my original post, where I logged the current state of things in a 6/17 update.  Thanks.

I am genuinely curious about your setup.  Please run lsb_release -a and sudo dnf repolist -all and paste it here.  I bet there is some strange difference.  It worked for you, so it should have worked for me.  See my initial post for my setup.

Per chance can you give me the output of lsb_release -a and sudo dnf repolist-all.  It will really help me solve this problem.
